# Chrome native drag-and-drop of relative container is not rendering ghost right

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

When you want `<div>` with relative position to be draggable, and this `<div>` has some absolutely positioned content, ghost image is not rendered right.

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0s3fxqnv/

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better getting a answer late than never; so it turns out te be a long standing bug in Google Chrome.

As I stumbled upon this recently, I opened a new issue at the Chromium bug tracker: [#617147](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617147). It seems it will be fixed soon, as current Dev and Canary versions do no longer have this false behaviour.

**Edit:**
Bug is fixed in Chrome v53.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Funny is that I can't remember where I was trying to solve this. But it is good to know.